# I got an error in pyhon, dumps with error on encoder.py

Tags: python

Can you help understand this error please

```
json_data = json.dumps(datagroup, encoding='latin1')
```

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 251, in dumps
>           sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 210, in encode
>           return ''.join(chunks)

Comment: can you please provide more information on what `datagroup` is?

Comment: it's simply an array